# python string convert into json for the bankstatement

Tags: python, json, string

This my input

```
string = '07/08/2018 07/08/2018 IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917 592674 5,000.00 39,325.93'
```

I need output like

```
{'date1':'07/08/2018','date2':'07/08/2018','remark':'IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917 592674','credit':'5,000.00','balance' : '39,325.93' }
```

I tried

```
result = { 'date1': list1[0], 'date2': list1[1], 'balance': list1[-1]}
print(result)
```

output

```
{'date1': '07/08/2018', 'date2': '07/08/2018', 'balance': '39,325.93'}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and describe exactly how it is not meeting your needs.

Comment: edit your post to include all relevant information - code, output, problem, question, etc. Don't forget to apply correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to split the string and use them as Scott mentioned, however if you can present it as a string in this format

```
str = '{'date1':'07/08/2018','date2':'07/08/2018','remark':'IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917 592674','credit':'5,000.00','balance' : '39,325.93' }'

#then you can just import json and do 

json = json.loads(str)
```

Comment: first, you cannot use single quotes to make it string as you have single quotes inside it too. then the resulting string is not valid json, so `json.loads()` will raise `JSONDecodeError`. There are other ways to convert such string to a dict object and then dump as json string (that's what OP is after). However if they had it in this format, they would have asked, don't you think?

Comment: also, asa side note - avoid using `str` as variable name - it's built-in function

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution -

```
 string = '07/08/2018 07/08/2018 IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917 592674 5,000.00 39,325.93'

 l = string.split()

 result = {'date1': l[0],
           'date2': l[1],
           'remark': ' '.join((l[2],l[3])),
           'credit': l[4],
           'balance': l[5]}
```

Output

```
 {'date1': '07/08/2018', 'date2': '07/08/2018', 'remark': 'IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917', 'credit': '592674', 'balance':'5,000.00'}
```

Comment: Use -2 in slicing -> " ".join(l[2:-2]) which considers elements leaving out last 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
words = string.split(" ")
values = words[:2] + [" ".join(words[2:-2])] +  words[-2:]
keys = ["date1", "date2", "remark", "credit", "balance"]
result = {}
for i in range(5):
    result[keys[i]] = values[i]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'date1': '07/08/2018',
 'date2': '07/08/2018',
 'remark': 'IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917 592674',
 'credit': '5,000.00',
 'balance': '39,325.93'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to get all parts of the remark in a single variable (a list)

```
import json

keys = ['date1', 'date2', 'remark', 'credit', 'balance']
foo = '07/08/2018 07/08/2018 IMPS DR-1763308000000116-PYTM0123456-917 592674 5,000.00 39,325.93'
date1, date2, *remarks, credit, balance = foo.split()
remarks = ' '.join(remarks)

#data as dict
data = dict(zip(keys, [date1, date2, remarks, credit, balance]))
print(data)

# if you need json string
my_json = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(my_json)
```

as a side note - don't use `string` as variable name - it's a module from python standard library.